# SQL: concatenate records from child table into single record

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 2 tables with 1:  M relation.
The join output shall have 2 columns:
1st column - from Parent table and
2nd column I a concatenation of all related records from the child table.
A total number of records in output shall be # of records in the parent table.
Database: MySQL.

Example:

Parent(id PK, parent_name)

Child (id PK, parent_id FK, child_name)

```
Parent:
| id | parent_name
——————------------
| 1  | Smith
| 2  | David

Child :
id | parent_id | child_name
———————————————---------------
1  | 1         | Anna
2  | 1         | Linda
3  | 2         | Maria
4  | 2         | Michael

Expected join result: 

parent_name | child_name
——————------|———————
Smith       | Anna, Linda
David       | Maria, Michael
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need group_concat. Try this -

```
SELECT P.parent_name, GROUP_CONCAT(C.child_name)
FROM Parent P INNER JOIN Child C
ON P.id = C.parent_id
GROUP BY P.parent_name
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select pr.parent_name,group_concat(ch.child_name) 
from parent pr join child ch 
where pr.id = ch.parent_id 
group by pr.parent_name;
```

Group concat is function in MySQL. You can use that.

Give a try :)